# How can I generate a stopwatch/countdown with the following code in C++?

Tags: c++, function, countdown, clock, stopwatch

I'm trying to create a timer function that prints a timer of 2 minutes (in M:S form) that ticks down by itself. I have the following code:

```
    void startTimer(){
    srand(time(0));

    clock_t start_t, end_t;
    clock_t start = clock();        
    clock_t end = clock();
    float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("%d", start, seconds);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have can measure the time that it takes to run a piece of code. What you need here is just to:

- Print the count down
- Sleep for one second

and do it in a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(){
  for (int i = 120; i >=0; i--){
    std::cout << std::to_string(i/60) <<":" << std::to_string(i%60) <<std::endl; 
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your code.

- What do you want to do with your random ?
- Why do you declare start_t and end_t ?
- What value do you think start and end will have ?
- What do you want to print?

If you want a 2 minutes timer, maybe you can use a loop from 120 to 0, with a printf (minutes = index / 60 and seconds = index % 60) and a 1 seconde sleep inside the loop. That will block the thread of the loop. Is that a problem?

If yes, you might want to take a look at other solutions, such as moving your loop inside another thread

Comment: This is not an answer.